# Swift...Change variable of .js file during runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

am working on an IOs application that has a WKwebview and i set the configuration to inject a .js file.

this is my javascript file.

```
var User = ""
var Pass = ""

document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = User
document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = password
submitButton()
```

now the code runs perfect when i give the variables value before hand.
however i am trying to change the value of User and Pass from NSUserDefualts later on but i have no idea where to start.

i tried playing around with javascript framework with no help.

any idea's or direction would be highly appreciated.

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i managed to work around the problem not going down the injecting javascriptfile path, i but by saving the user and pass variables in NSUserDefaults and running the javascript from a method inside my UIViewController

the code is not pretty but it works and looks something like this:

```
// the passed would be stored in NSUserDefaults

let passwd = "test"

// passEdited simply adds ' ' to the passwd you can just add them to the passwd variable but i like to see every step i am taking
let passEdited = "'" + passwd  +"'"

// this is the actual java code i would like to run
var passJS = "document.getElementByName('password')[0].value =" + passEdited

// check for correct Url before running the java code
if webView.URL?.absoluteString == "www.YOURWEBSITE" {
webView.evaluteJavaScript(passJS, completionHandler: nil)
```