# Change variable value to javascript from Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I run an app with `WKWebview`. I know that I can pass data from `JS to Swift` via `postMessage`.
But how i can achieve the opposite one? I need `Swift to give data to Javascript`. I can see some examples that using `evaluateJavaScript` but can't figure out how that's working.
This is a sample example/code :

**Javascript**

```
 var dataString = "";

 function getDataFromSwift(data){
    dataString = data
 }
```

I need above function to "communicate" with `Swift` and change the value of var "dataString".
I notice that if I run `evaluateJavaScript` doesn't change "dataString" value to JS.

**Swift 3**

```
let callMethod = String(format: "getDataFromSwift('\("some text")')")
webView.evaluateJavaScript(callMethod, completionHandler: { (obj, error) -> Void in })
```

Comment: are you using webview delegate method , you need to send value as parameter and then you can fetch through delegate method , parameter .

Comment: Shobhakar if you mean func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {} yes i try from there. I know that method being called because on my tests i can print or take a return from function, but i need to change JS value.

Comment: You want to change js value from swift code , is it ?

Comment: Exactly. Its just a sample code. My point is that i want to make real changes to JS Native values from Swift.

Comment: did u try this code : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30613379/3400991

Comment: didn't make it with this code also

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Have you tried to do a `console.log` of dataString after you set it? When are you trying to access it with the new value that you think is not set? Can you post more of the js code that doesn't use the latest value of `dataString`?